# How to filter data using datetime picker?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I use `Date` as datatype in MySQL server and insert `mydate` as:

```
datetimepicker1.value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

It was successfully inserted, but when I search the data using a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CDate BETWEEN datetimepicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                AND datetimepicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

It returns zero rows as result.

Comment: Why is there C# code in your SQL? You should be using parameterized SQL queries.

Comment: DateTime are not strings. You shouldn't pass a string to insert, update or search a datetime column. Use parameters of the correct type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use **quote**. Try this :

```
string.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CDate BETWEEN '{0}'AND '{1}'", 
    dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
);
```